# Difference between being asymptotic and equivalent?

Tags: calculus, asymptotics

I can't understand the difference between these two definitions

> A function $f$ is said to be asymptotic to a function $g$ as $x \to +\infty$ if
>   $lim_{x\to +\infty} f(x)-g(x)=0$

That means $f(x)=g(x)+o(1)$ as $x\to +\infty$

> A function $f$ is said to be equivalent to a function $g$ as $x \to c \in \mathbb{R} \cup \big\{+\infty,-\infty \big \}$ if
>   $lim_{x\to c} \frac{f(x)}{g(x)}=1$. In that case we write $f \sim g$ as $x\to c$

This means  $f(x)=g(x)+o(g)$ as $x\to c$

What are the relation and the difference between the two?

I think that this relation:

$f=o(g)$ as $x\to c$
$\implies$ $f=o(1)$ as $x\to c$

holds when $g \sim x^{n}$ whith $n>1$ as $x\to c$

So if $f$ is asymptotic to $g$ then is it also equivalent to it?

Secondly I found the first definition just for $x \to +\infty$ but is it valid also for $x \to c \in \mathbb{R}$ ?

Thanks in advice for your help

Comment: If  you "think" that is the relation, why not try to prove it?

Comment: Relation depends on how between $g$ and $1$. If $g=O(1)$, the latter implies the former. If $g=\Omega(1)$, the former implies the latter. If both, (that is $g=\Theta(1)$) the two are equivalent.